# Displaying all the lines of a query even its a null value

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT A.HOUR,A.ACTUAL_COUNT,B.EXPECTED_COUNT 
FROM (
    SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM REPORT_INQUIRY_DT) HOUR ,COUNT(1) ACTUAL_COUNT
    FROM SBE_RPT_INQ_OUTPUT
    WHERE TO_CHAR(REPORT_INQUIRY_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2015-04-19' 
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM REPORT_INQUIRY_DT)
    ORDER BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM REPORT_INQUIRY_DT)
) A
left outer JOIN (
    SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM REPORT_INQUIRY_DT) AS HOUR,
        ROUND(COUNT(1)/4) EXPECTED_COUNT
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM SBE_RPT_INQ_OUTPUT
        WHERE TO_CHAR(REPORT_INQUIRY_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD')=TO_CHAR((SELECT SYSDATE -7 FROM DUAL),'YYYY-MM-DD')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * 
        FROM SBE_RPT_INQ_OUTPUT
        WHERE TO_CHAR(REPORT_INQUIRY_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD')=TO_CHAR((SELECT SYSDATE -14 FROM DUAL),'YYYY-MM-DD')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * 
        FROM SBE_RPT_INQ_OUTPUT
        WHERE TO_CHAR(REPORT_INQUIRY_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD')=TO_CHAR((SELECT SYSDATE -21 FROM DUAL),'YYYY-MM-DD')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * 
        FROM SBE_RPT_INQ_OUTPUT
        WHERE TO_CHAR(REPORT_INQUIRY_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD')=TO_CHAR((SELECT SYSDATE -34 FROM DUAL),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    ) A
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM A.REPORT_INQUIRY_DT)
    ORDER BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM A.REPORT_INQUIRY_DT) 
) B
ON A.HOUR=B.HOUR;
```

and the answer i am getting.

```
hour Actual_Count Expect_count
7    2            0
```

I want to display all the hourly transaction even if its not `null`.

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` shows all the rows in the first subquery, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` shows all the rows in the second subquery. Try `FULL OUTER JOIN` if you need all the rows in either query.

Comment: Why don't show a sort of expected output and why don't explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Barmar i ahve tried that before..  1
  1
  1
7 2 0
  2
9 2 2
  3
  4
13 2 15
14 7 11
15 8 8
  22
17 1 6
18 2 3
19 5 1
  1
  1
  1
5 1 
21 2

Comment: It displays null in hhour place also prints null in the actual count..i want to print 0 in the actual count and hour should be printed 1,2,3...24

Comment: @chandankumarbrahma: Please include the expected output in the question itself. Furthermore, it would be helpful to add some sample data from the source tables.

Answer (score 0):

I see something strange in your query, but, in absence of any requirement description, I can only assume it's exactly what you want to extract with the exception that you're not getting any rows for the hours with missing values.

So to get the missing values you could try this query:

```
with hours as (
        select rownum-1 as hour
        from dual
        connect by rownum <= 24
    )
select h.HOUR, count(*)
from hours h
    left join (
            select *
            from SBE_RPT_INQ_OUTPUT t 
            where t.REPORT_INQUIRY_DT >= (trunc(sysdate)-(34))
                and t.REPORT_INQUIRY_DT < trunc(sysdate)
        ) t
        on (
            mod(trunc(t.REPORT_INQUIRY_DT)-trunc(sysdate)) in (7,14,21,34)
            and hour = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM REPORT_INQUIRY_DT)
        )
group by h.HOUR
```

Anyway it's hard to understand why you don't want to match occurrences of the days ago between 0 to 6, 8 to 13, 15 to 20 and 22 to 33.

**Update**

To get the count of hourly occurrences of the current day and the average hourly count for the past 4 weeks you could use this other query

```
with hours as (
        select rn, mod(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM systimestamp) + 24 - rn,24) as hour
        from (
                select rownum-1 as rn
                from dual
                connect by rownum <= 24
            )
    )
select sysdate, HOUR as hour, nvl(avg,0) as avg, nvl(current_count,0) as current_count
from hours h
    left join (
            select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM REPORT_INQUIRY_DT) as hour, 
                count(case when t.REPORT_INQUIRY_DT < trunc(sysdate) then 1 end)/(4*7) as avg,
                count(case when t.REPORT_INQUIRY_DT >= trunc(sysdate) then 1 end) as current_count
            from SBE_RPT_INQ_OUTPUT t 
            where t.REPORT_INQUIRY_DT >= (trunc(sysdate)-(4*7))
            group by EXTRACT(HOUR FROM REPORT_INQUIRY_DT)
        ) t using (hour)
order by rn
```

Comment: sir thanks but i want hourly count in the 2nd column in my query and 3rd column takes the avg count og last 4 weeks and till the current hour and 1st colunm is hour.please suggest by editing my original query and hour is not the table name ..i am extracting hour from report_inquiry date column..please see my query and suggest

Comment: ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source 30076. 00000 - "invalid extract field for extract source" *Cause: The extract source does not contain the specified extract field. *Action: Error at Line: 2 Column: 37 error.. also i want the count till the current hour.my script wil run hurly basis  and will run 24 times in a day please suggest

Comment: I changed sysdate with systimestamp in the query

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 37  still gettignerror

Comment: I don't have a DB server to test, it was a typo error for the "count(count(" now it should be fine.

Comment: rn is not need sir hour actual count and expected count should be the output

Comment: sir see my original query ..my query is not displaying when actual count is 0 and expected count is 5 for example.like that and hour should be extracted from REPORT_INQUIRY_DT column and on this hourly basis till the current hour i want to dispaly count and expected count like 1 st hour 5 10 2nd hour 2 15 like this

Comment: I can't understand well your excepted output, why don't edit your question?

Comment: agin ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 13 Column: 80 showing in ur quesy please edit my original qury if i extract hour from systemtimestamp it will work but not solve my purpose .i want to monitoe my databse trans hourly please check

Comment: sir expected count is the avg og last 4 weeks til the cuurent hour count..so that i can verify my transctions are working fine or not

Comment: The query works fine now, you have the data and you can verify. But the query is ok, I made a test here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/5435

Comment: HOUR|ACTUAL_COUNT|EXPECTED_COUNT                                          ----------|------------|--------------                                                              
         0|           1|             5                                                              
         1|           6|             5                                                              
         2|           1|             4                                                              
                                                     output like this will continue up to 24 when i will last ran at 00:00

Comment: Edit your question to describe your expected output so you can format it properly

Comment: is is working fine sir but on hourly basis if it will run will it give the correct output i doubt  and i have send a sample output as i want hour column should be from 1 to 24 and as per the hour extracted from REPORT_INQUIRY_DT column

Comment: I think I understood the problem now: hours where going forward in the past query now they're going backward from last hour to 24 hours ago

Comment: Yes sir absolutely right and i want print 0 when count is null here in your query displayed null and please just edit my original query it will easier for me to understand

Comment: That's what it does now

Comment: So why don't vote and mark this as the right answer? Where are your good manners gone?

Comment: Sir thank you I haven't checked thank you very much for your time and it is absolutely right i think

Comment: hello sir still the hour colukn is not showing from 1 to 24 rather it is dhowing 12 11...0 23 22...12 please suggest

Comment: Time goes backward from current hour to 24 hours ago as you requested. With 24 hours time fornat midnight is shown as 0 not as 24. If you prefer to see hours from 1 to 24 just change hour to hour + 1 in the main select clause